# bluedart shipping integration for opencart(2.0.3.1)?

Tags: php, opencart2.x

I have developed an online store on opencart(2.0.3.1) e commerce platform. Now I need to integrate bluedart shiping module for shiping methods.Is there any way to implement/integrate it in opencart? thanks in advance

Comment: actually this is the first time iam doing this iam new to this opencart want to know where to start

Comment: [see this](https://www.google.co.in/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=bluedart+for+open+cart&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=DMBSVpSVIJvmugS6npLoCg)

Answer (score 0):

If you login into the admin panel of your opencart webshop you can see in the menu something called Extensions Installer. I don't know Bluedart but i see there [is an extension called Bluedart on the website of opencart.](http://www.opencart.com/?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=19543)

When you have bought it you can import it by either uploading the contents of the zipfile to the desired location (mostly provided in a readme file) or by using the Extensions Installer where you upload the zip file.

Comment: yes i have see that extension for that i need to buy that extension ,that why iam asking is there any other way

Comment: Another way is by implementing the api yourself. So yes you have to buy it or let someone else buy it for you